# Schengen Tourism Visa Field 20 "Residence in a country other than the country of current nationality"

Tags: visas, schengen

I am South African, currently living in the United States, working on my F-1 student visa (first year on OPT). I am applying for a Schengen Tourism Visa and I am not sure what to say for part 20, "Residence in a country other than the country of current nationality." Do I tick no or yes? If yes, I am not sure how to fill in the blanks: "Residence permit or equivalent ***(1)***____ No. ***(2)***____ Valid until ***(3)***____" Will I be inputing the details from my F-1 visa? In other words (1) F-1 visa, (2) number in red on my visa and (3) expiry date? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

> Do I tick no or yes?

Your residence is in a country other than the country of which you are a citizen.
Therefore, you should tick *yes.*

> If yes, I am not sure how to fill in the blanks: "Residence permit or equivalent (1)____ No. (2)____ Valid until (3)____" Will I be inputing the details from my F-1 visa?

You should read and follow any instructions given by the embassy responsible for your visa application.  For example, if you are applying [in New York for a visa to go to Italy](https://consnewyork.esteri.it/consolato_newyork/en/i_servizi/per_chi_si_reca_in_italia/forms.html):

> If you are not a U.S. citizen and you need to apply for a visa, you must provide a copy of the title that allows you to reside legally in the U.S. (U.S. long term visa with exclusion of B1/B2, U.S. permanent resident card, I-20, I-797, resident alien card). The title must have a validity of at least 3 months beyond the last day of your trip in the Schengen Area.

This doesn't much help, unfortunately.  If I were you, and if the country you're applying to is similarly unhelpful, I would put the visa details *and* the I-20 details, just to be safe.  I would probably also include details of the I-94, just to be safe.

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite this simple.  A F-1 visa holder is considered a NON-Resident Alien by the US for their first 5 years. Only after that time are they considered a Resident Alien. However by other definitions the OP would indeed be a resident.

Comment: @Doc residence for income tax status is irrelevant to the Schengen requirement to apply in the consulate responsible for the place of residence, as it is irrelevant to every purpose other than US income taxation.